# Numpy: how to roll 1 "row" in an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm creating an 2d numpy array, with a simplified example like something like this:

```
COL01 = np.array(["A", "D", "G"])
COL02 = np.array(["B", "E", "H"])
COL03 = np.array(["C", "F", "I"])

GRID = np.array([[COL01], [COL02], [COL03]])
```

I'm passing the GRID around in my code.  I want to be able to modify GRID by rolling ONLY one of the arrays that makes up its component rows.  For instance, I want to pass GRID into a function with a row number and number of positions to roll, and then return the result.

How can I roll the single row independently?  I tried following the answer from here:
[[Roll rows of a matrix independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360675/roll-rows-of-a-matrix-independently]), but I couldn't figure out how to adapt that answer to my problem.

Comment: either pass the columns around and roll them before constructing `GRID` or break `GRID` back into columns, roll one, and reconstruct `GRID`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the row you want to operate on and using [`numpy.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).

Let's say we want to roll the first row one place to the right:

```
import numpy as np

grid = np.array([['A', 'D', 'G'],
                 ['B', 'E', 'H'],
                 ['C', 'F', 'I']])

grid[0] = np.roll(grid[0], 1)
print grid
```

This yields:

```
[['G' 'A' 'D']
 ['B' 'E' 'H']
 ['C' 'F' 'I']]
```

Notice that we're modifying the original array.

You should decide whether you want to operate on the array in-place (modifying the original) or if you want to make a copy each time.  Repeated calls will have different effects depending on what you decide:

```
import numpy as np

def independent_roll_inplace(arr, ind, amount):
    arr[ind] = np.roll(arr[ind], amount)

def independent_roll_copy(arr, ind, amount):
    arr = arr.copy()
    arr[ind] = np.roll(arr[ind], amount)
    return arr

grid = np.array([['A', 'D', 'G'],
                 ['B', 'E', 'H'],
                 ['C', 'F', 'I']])
```

As an example of the difference, if we make a copy each time, we start "fresh" with the original grid.  Repeated calls have no effect on the original:

```
print 'Roll the second row one place'
print independent_roll_copy(grid, 1, 1)
print 'Roll the second row two places'
print independent_roll_copy(grid, 1, 2)
print 'Roll the second row three places'
print independent_roll_copy(grid, 1, 3)
```

This yields:

```
Roll the second row one place
[['A' 'D' 'G']
 ['H' 'B' 'E']
 ['C' 'F' 'I']]
Roll the second row two places
[['A' 'D' 'G']
 ['E' 'H' 'B']
 ['C' 'F' 'I']]
Roll the second row three places
[['A' 'D' 'G']
 ['B' 'E' 'H']
 ['C' 'F' 'I']]
```

However, if we're modifying the original each time, we'd get the same result by rolling one place multiple times:

```
for _ in range(3):
    print 'Roll the first row one place, modifying the original'
    independent_roll_inplace(grid, 0, 1)
    print grid
```

Yielding:

```
Roll the second row one place, modifying the original
[['A' 'D' 'G']
 ['H' 'B' 'E']
 ['C' 'F' 'I']]
Roll the second row one place, modifying the original
[['A' 'D' 'G']
 ['E' 'H' 'B']
 ['C' 'F' 'I']]
Roll the second row one place, modifying the original
[['A' 'D' 'G']
 ['B' 'E' 'H']
 ['C' 'F' 'I']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might solve your problem.

REV_GRID is the rolled over version of GRID.

```
COL01 = ["A", "D", "G"]
COL02 = ["B", "E", "H"]
COL03 = ["C", "F", "I"]

GRID = []
GRID.append(COL01)
GRID.append(COL02)
GRID.append(COL03)

REV_GRID = []

for col in GRID:
    REV_GRID.append(col[::-1])

print GRID
print REV_GRID
```

Please let me know if it does not solve your problem. We will work on that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this shifts the values in each of the rows.  I want to be able to arbitrarily pick one of the rows and roll the values of that array only.

Comment: That can be done as well.
In the above example, let say you want to roll COL02
That can be done by:

COL02 = GRID[1]
REV_COL02 = COL02[::-1]

COL02 = ["B", "E", "H"]
REV_COL02 = ["H", "E", "B"]

I hope that it will solve your problem.
Please let me know if I have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: I chose Joe Kington's answer because I don't have to deconstruct and reassemble the grid.