# Align dataframe diagonals into columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, diagonal

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
        [3, 4, 5, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
    ], list('abcde'), list('ABCDE'))
```

How do I align the diagonal values into columns?

I'd like this as the result

[image]

---

***i've done this***

```
pd.DataFrame([np.roll(row, -k) for k, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows())],
             df.index, df.columns)
```

I'm hoping for something more straight forward.

Comment: pandas.Index.diagonal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use numpy [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360675/roll-rows-of-a-matrix-independently) - for shift is used reversed `Series` same length as `DataFrame` (if `DataFrame` has non numeric and non monotonic index it works nice also):

```
A = df.values
r = pd.Series(range(len(df)))[::-1] + 1

rows, column_indices = np.ogrid[:A.shape[0], :A.shape[1]]

r[r < 0] += A.shape[1]
column_indices = column_indices - r[:,np.newaxis]

result = A[rows, column_indices]
print (pd.DataFrame(result, df.index, df.columns))
   A  B  C  D  E
a  1  2  3  4  5
b  1  2  3  4  5
c  1  2  3  4  5
d  1  2  3  4  5
e  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
a = df.values
n = a.shape[1]
r = np.arange(n)
col = np.mod(r[:,None] + r,n)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(a[np.arange(n)[:,None],col],columns=df.columns)
```