# shift diagonal of numpy array to left and pad

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shift

consider the below 2D numpy array

```
array1 = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                   [ 5, 21, 15,  8, 12],
                   [ 2,  3,  4,  8,  3],
                   [ 3,  4,  5, 17, 41],
                   [ 4, 20,  7,  5,  6]])
```

my desired output is to shift the array at its diagonal to the left and pad the empty elements with `np.nan`

desired output

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [21., 15.,  8., 12., nan],
       [4.,  8.,  3., nan, nan],
       [17., 41., nan, nan, nan],
       [6., nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Would it always have the same elements across all rows?

Comment: No. the elements values across rows will vary

Comment: Could you update with more representative sample data, i.e. different elements in different rows, so that people don't assume otherwise?

Comment: Use Divakar's function like this: `strided_indexing_roll(array1, -np.arange(len(array1)))`

Comment: I tried using @Divakar's strided function. But that solution is to roll rows starting from different index location for each row. it does not answer part of my question related to shifting to the left and padding empty elements to the right with np.nan

Comment: @SirajS. Isn't that strided one giving you the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar. the function here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360675/roll-rows-of-a-matrix-independently) rolls the rows independently but starts with first element, i want the diagonal element to shift to the left.

Comment: @SirajS. I understand what you want. On that doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614167/ work with `strided_indexing_roll(array1, -np.arange(len(array1)))` giving you what you want?

Comment: @Divakar, yes. this works perfect. thank you.