# How to reference Column data in a rolling window calculation? Error ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I am currently working on a large DF and need to reference the data in a column for a rolling window calculation. All rows have a separate rolling window value so i need to reference the column but i am getting the out put

```
    ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(20, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))
    
    df['op'] = (np.random.randint(0,20, size=20))

        a   b   c   d   op
    0   6   17  3   5   9
    1   8   3   13  7   2
    2   19  12  18  3   8
    3   8   8   5   4   17
    4   0   5   9   3   19
    5   0   5   19  9   11
    6   7   7   13  8   10
    7   7   5   12  0   4
    8   13  17  4   4   17
    9   7   0   16  9   7
    10  7   8   13  10  13
    11  18  3   1   11  16
    12  4   4   5   13  4
    13  9   8   14  19  9
    14  13  10  10  7   10
    15  9   16  11  16  3
    16  5   7   3   0   11
    17  13  14  10  1   16
    18  6   14  13  4   18
    19  1   9   8   0   19
```

trying to reference the value in df['op'] for a rolling average.

```
    df['SMA'] = df.a.rolling(window=df.op).mean()
```

produces Error ValueError: window must be an integer 0 or greater

As mentioned i am working on a large data frame so the above is example code.

Comment: You can build a custom function, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919277/rolling-sum-on-a-dynamic-window

Comment: Thank you for the link it was a big help in me fixing the problem that i'd been stuck on for days.

Answer (score 3):

Solution

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(20, 4)), 
    columns=list('abcd'))
    
    df['op'] = (np.random.randint(0,20, size=20))

    def lookback_window(row, values, lookback, method='mean', *args, **kwargs):
        loc = values.index.get_loc(row.name)
        lb = lookback.loc[row.name]
        return getattr(values.iloc[loc - lb: loc + 1], method)(*args, **kwargs)

    df['SMA'] = df.apply(lookback_window, values=df['a'], lookback=df['op'], axis=1)


    df

    a      b    c   d   op  SMA
    0   17  19  11  9   0   17.000000
    1   0   10  9   11  19  NaN
    2   13  8   11  2   16  NaN
    3   9   2   4   4   8   NaN
    4   11  10  0   17  18  NaN
    5   14  19  17  10  17  NaN
    6   6   12  17  1   4   10.600000
    7   10  1   3   18  2   10.000000
    8   7   6   12  3   19  NaN
    9   1   9   7   5   9   8.800000
    10  17  1   3   13  1   9.000000
    11  19  17  0   2   7   10.625000
    12  18  5   2   4   12  10.923077
    13  18  5   4   2   1   18.000000
    14  5   11  17  11  11  11.250000
    15  16  9   2   11  16  NaN
    16  15  17  1   8   14  11.933333
    17  15  2   0   3   6   15.142857
    18  18  3   18  3   10  13.545455
    19  7   0   12  15  3   13.750000
```