# Subtract pandas dataframe using list to choose diferent columns in each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a list as an index in a Dataframe subtract operation. However I get the following error: *cannot do positional indexing on Index with these indexers*

I have these two DataFrames:

**df1**:

| index | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | ... | t950 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a,1 | 0,00001 | 0,00002 | 0,00003 | 0,00004 | 0,00008 | ... | 0,00004 |
| a,2 | 0,00001 | 0,00002 | 0,00003 | 0,00005 | 0,00007 | ... | 0,00004 |
| b,1 | 0,00004 | 0,00003 | 0,00002 | 0,00006 | 0,00006 | ... | 0,00001 |
| b,2 | 0,00005 | 0,00004 | 0,00003 | 0,00007 | 0,00005 | ... | 0,00002 |

**df2**:

| index | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | ... | t950 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a,1 | 0,00008 | 0,00007 | 0,00007 | 0,00006 | 0,00004 | ... | 0,00002 |
| a,2 | 0,00007 | 0,00006 | 0,00005 | 0,00004 | 0,00003 | ... | 0,00002 |
| b,1 | 0,00002 | 0,00001 | 0,00002 | 0,00003 | 0,00004 | ... | 0,00004 |
| b,2 | 0,00005 | 0,00006 | 0,00007 | 0,00008 | 0,00009 | ... | 0,00004 |

And I have a list too which includes the index for each column from where the subtract should start:

**index_col**

[2,3,1,2]

My code nowadays is as follows:

```py
result=df1.subtract(df2.iloc[:,index_col:].rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.iloc[:,index_col:].columns,df2.columns))
```

My expected result is:

| index | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | ... | t950 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a,1 | -0,00006 | -0,00004 | -0,00001 | ... | ... | ... | 0,00002 |
| a,2 | -0,00003 | -0,00001 | ... | ... | ... | ... | 0,00002 |
| b,1 | -0,00003 | -0,00001 | 0,00001 | -0,00002 | ... | ... | 0,00004 |
| b,2 | -0,00002 | -0,00004 | -0,00006 | ... | ... | ... | 0,00004 |

Where, for example, in the first row:

t1 - t3 // t2 - t4 // t3 - t5 because in df2 it should start in the third column (as the first index_col value reflects).

Do you know how I can calculate this subtract following my list as a column index ? I know I can do this with a loop but I want to try to avoid it and use the power of vectorization.

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the operation? It is not clear for me if you want to substract columns / rows ...

Comment: @Zaero Divide I just add more information to my question. At the end I want to subtract columns but for each row it should start in a different column based on the list values.

Comment: Just thinking out loud. I think I would convert both of these to numpy, then create a version of `df2` where the rows had been rotated by the number of steps you specify.  After that, I could do `df1-df2` without any nonsense.

Comment: Ah, I see. First row is df1 - df2/offset2. Second row is df1-df2/offset3.
I agree with @TimRoberts answer, but vectorized implementation is not easy, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200369/shift-rows-of-a-numpy-array-independently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to subtract 0 when the row runs out.

Let `shifts` be the list `[2,3,1,2]`, what you call index_col.

Might not be the nicest/most elegant solution, but I think this will do what you want:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import shift

shifted = np.vstack([shift(row, -k) for row, k in zip(df2.values, shifts)])
result = df1 - shifted
```

Full example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage import shift


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4, 5)), index=list("ABCD"), columns=list("abcde"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4, 5)))
shifts = [2, 3, 1, 2]
```

```py
>>> df1
          a         b         c         d         e
A  0.308420  0.591043  0.914204  0.407474  0.670670
B  0.371686  0.989710  0.823255  0.145337  0.437014
C  0.023323  0.590014  0.685122  0.558222  0.238016
D  0.996939  0.974608  0.117192  0.539702  0.622569

>>> df2
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.825861  0.356216  0.668553  0.090403  0.915279
1  0.699088  0.239835  0.728388  0.143411  0.025266
2  0.600219  0.280567  0.267376  0.100538  0.511053
3  0.538059  0.705963  0.633112  0.138550  0.455539

>>> shifted = np.vstack([shift(row, -k) for row, k in zip(df2.values, shifts)])
>>> df1 - shifted
          a         b         c         d         e
A -0.360133  0.500640 -0.001074  0.407474  0.670670
B  0.228275  0.964444  0.823255  0.145337  0.437014
C -0.257244  0.322639  0.584583  0.047168  0.238016
D  0.363827  0.836059 -0.338347  0.539702  0.622569
```

If you don't want to import `scipy`, you can write your own `shift` function: see [Shift elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399534/shift-elements-in-a-numpy-array).