# Iteratively pop and append to generate new lists using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, append

I have a list of elements `mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and would like to iteratively:

1. copy the list
2. pop the first element of the copied list
3. and append it to the end of the copied list
4. repeat this for the next row, etc.

Desired output:

```
index   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
0       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1       2   3   4   5   6   7   8   1
2       3   4   5   6   7   8   1   2
3       4   5   6   7   8   1   2   3
4       5   6   7   8   1   2   3   4
5       6   7   8   1   2   3   4   5
6       7   8   1   2   3   4   5   6
7       8   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

I suspect a `for` loop is needed but am having trouble iteratively generating rows based on the prior row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `slicing` ([Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)) is what you are looking for:

```
next_iteration =  my_list[1:] + [my_list[0]]
```

and the full loop:

```
output = []
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    output.append(my_list[i:] + my_list[:i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`this numpy solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272600/2901002) with `rolls` create by `np.arange`:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

a = np.array(mylist)
rolls = np.arange(0, -8, -1)
print (rolls)
[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7]

df = pd.DataFrame(a[(np.arange(len(a))[:,None]-rolls) % len(a)], 
                  columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2
3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3
4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

If need loop solution (slow) is possible use [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

rolls = np.arange(0, -8, -1)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.roll(mylist, i) for i in rolls], 
                  columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2
3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3
4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ar = np.roll(np.array(mylist), 1)
data = [ar := np.roll(ar, -1) for _ in range(ar.size)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[*'ABCDEFGH'])
print(df)
>>>
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2
3  4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3
4  5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```