# Padding rows based on conditional

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have time series data per row (with columns as time steps) and I'd like to left and right pad each row with 0s based on a conditional row value (i.e. 'Padding amount'). This is what I have:

```
Padding amount     T1     T2     T3
   0               3      2.9    2.8
   1               2.9    2.8    2.7
   1               2.8    2.3    2.0
   2               4.4    3.3    2.3
```

And this is what I'd like to produce:

```
Padding amount     T1     T2     T3     T4     T5
   0               3      2.9    2.8    0      0    (--> padding = 0, so no change)
   1               0      2.9    2.8    2.7    0    (--> shifted one to the left)
   1               0      2.8    2.3    2.0    0
   2               0      0      4.4    3.3    2.3  (--> shifted two to the right)
```

I see that `Keras` has sequence padding, but not sure how this would work considering all rows have the same number of entries. I'm looking at `Shift` and `np.roll` but I'm sure a solution exists for this already somewhere.

Comment: it is not exactly a dupe but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360675/roll-rows-of-a-matrix-independently) could help you, except you need to create the missing columns first I guess

Comment: Why do you have a numpy tag?

Answer (score 2):

In numpy, you could construct an array of indices for the locations where you want to place your array elements.

Let's say you have

```
padding = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2])
data = np.array([[3.0, 2.9, 2.8],
                 [2.9, 2.8, 2.7],
                 [2.8, 2.3, 2.0],
                 [4.4, 3.3, 2.3]])
M, N = data.shape
```

The output array would be

```
output = np.zeros((M, N + padding.max()))
```

You can make an index of where the data goes:

```
rows = np.arange(M)[:, None]
cols = padding[:, None] + np.arange(N)
```

Since the shape of the index broadcasts to the shape of the shape of the data, you can assign the output directly:

```
output[rows, cols] = data
```

Not sure how this applies to a `DataFrame` exactly, but you could probably construct a new one after operating on the `values` of the old one. Alternatively, you could probably implement all these operations equivalently directly in pandas.

Comment: if you construct `padding=df['Padding_amount'].to_numpy()` and `data=df.filter(regex='T\d').to_numpy()` where `df` is OP's dataframe, then putting back the `output` is less obvious but can be done with `df[[f'T{i}' for i in range(1, output.shape[1]+1)]] = pd.DataFrame(output, index=df.index)`, anyway your method is really nice

Comment: @Ben.T thanks. I'm not really a pandas guy so that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it, i've made the process really flexible in terms of how many time periods/steps it can take:

```
import pandas as pd

#data
d = {'Padding amount': [0, 1, 1, 2],
 'T1': [3, 2.9, 2.8, 4.4],
 'T2': [2.9, 2.7, 2.3, 3.3],
 'T3': [2.8, 2.7, 2.0, 2.3]}
#create DF
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
#get max padding amount
maxPadd = df['Padding amount'].max()
#list of time periods
timePeriodsCols = [c for c in df.columns.tolist() if 'T' in c]
#reverse list
reverseList = timePeriodsCols[::-1]
#number of periods
noOfPeriods = len(timePeriodsCols)

#create new needed columns
for i in range(noOfPeriods + 1, noOfPeriods + 1 + maxPadd):
    df['T' + str(i)] = ''

#loop over records
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #get padding amount
    padAmount = df.at[i, 'Padding amount']
    #if zero then do nothing
    if padAmount == 0:
        continue
    #else: roll column value by padding amount and set old location to zero
    else:
        for col in reverseList:
            df.at[i, df.columns[df.columns.get_loc(col) + padAmount]] = df.at[i, df.columns[df.columns.get_loc(col)]]
            df.at[i, df.columns[df.columns.get_loc(col)]] = 0

print(df)

   Padding amount   T1   T2   T3   T4   T5
0               0  3.0  2.9  2.8          
1               1  0.0  2.9  2.7  2.7     
2               1  0.0  2.8  2.3    2     
3               2  0.0  0.0  4.4  3.3  2.3
```