# Roll rows of a matrix independently using numpy.roll

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to roll a 2D numpy array, each row being rolled by an amount defined in a 1D array.
For example, I have

```
A=np.array([[1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]])

r=[1,2,2]
```

And I wish to perform the following task:

```
C=np.copy(A)
for i in range(3):
    C[i]=np.roll(C[i],r[i])
print(C)

[[3 1 2]
 [5 6 4]
 [8 9 7]]
```

Apparently, numpy roll function supports arrays as input. But the way it works is puzzling, and I don't get what I think I *should* get:

```
B=np.roll(A,r,1)
print(B)

[[2 3 1]
 [5 6 4]
 [8 9 7]]
```

Here, all the rows have been shifted by the same amount (which from my experiments seems to be the sum of the elements of my 1D array). What did I do wrong here? numpy.roll is much faster than a for loop, so I'd like to use it if possible, but I can't get it to output what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) it explains:

*shiftint or tuple of ints
The number of places by which elements are shifted. If a tuple, then axis must be a tuple of the same size, and each of the given axes is shifted by the corresponding number. If an int while axis is a tuple of ints, then the same value is used for all given axes.*

Which explains when you feed shift as tuple, you need to feed the axis a same sized tuple, and each dimension is rolled a constant number that is its corresponding value in the shift tuple.

For example, `np.roll(A, (4,3), (1,2))` shifts the `axis=1` 4 steps and `axis=2` 3 steps.

To achieve your goal, please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360675/roll-rows-of-a-matrix-independently) for many sophisticated solutions.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what the numpy.roll function does, then. Thanks for the example, it made it clearer (it's a shame the numpy documentation doesn't have an example for the case of shifts in an array). And thank you for the link. I just thought numpy.roll did what is decribed there.