# How can i store the list elements in first row and first colomn of the matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I want to store the list elements as the first row and colomn in a matrix in python

```
myLIST=[41,32,49,4,55]
```

after that i want to create a matrix of size =(m,n) where m and n = length of (myLIST);
such that:

```
myMATRIX=[ [41,32,49,4,55], [32,0,0,0,0] ,[49,0,0,0,0], [4,0,0,0,0], [55,0,0,0,0] ]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This is pretty basic Python coding.

Comment: I have a matrix with all values 0; now i want to interchange the 1st row and 1st column of the matrix with the elements of a list which is given

Comment: Yes, we know.  What code do you have?  Are you using numpy?

Comment: No i am thinking about if we can do using list comprehension... i don't use external libraries as i am new in CP

Comment: If you already HAVE a matrix of zeros, then no, you don't need a list comprehension.  You need a simple `for` loop.

Comment: i mean yes we can do...but i am trying to learn list comprehension..i am thinking if we can solve it using the list comprehension only?

Comment: I have added an approach with list comprehension and ternary operator which lets you add conditions to each element in a list comprehension. Hope that gives you some guidance in your quest to learn list comprehensions.

Comment: You need to use the right tool for the job.  You don't use a screwdriver to drive a nail just because you want to learn the screwdriver.  `for i in range(5):` / `myMATRIX[i,0] = myMATRIX[0,i] = myLIST[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
lst = [41,32,49,4,55]

n = len(lst)
output = [[lst[max(i, j)] if i * j == 0 else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

print(output)
# [[41, 32, 49, 4, 55], [32, 0, 0, 0, 0], [49, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [55, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Normally the pattern `for ... in range(len(...))` is ugly, but in this case I find it better than using `for ... in enumerate(...)`.

Note that we are assigning a value from `lst` when and only when `i * j == 0`, i.e., at the first row or at the first column; this is done by `... if ... else ...`.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions can be very useful but sometimes they become so complex/unreadable that IMO it's better to use *for* loops for the sake of clarity at the possible cost of efficiency. Never forget that someone else may need to amend your code one day and they could spend an awful lot of time unravelling your list/dictionary/set comprehension.

Having said that, you could do this:

```
myLIST = [41, 32, 49, 4, 55]
myMATRIX = [myLIST] + [[e] + [0] * (len(myLIST)-1) for e in myLIST[1:]]
print(myMATRIX)
```

**Output:**

```
[[41, 32, 49, 4, 55], [32, 0, 0, 0, 0], [49, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [55, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using only list comprehensions

Here is one way you can do this using `enumerate`. The logic is as below -

1. Iterate over each element of the myLIST with enumerate to get their index position.
2. If position is greater than 0th index, return the specific element along with a list of 0s
3. Else, return the complete list when index is 0.

```
[[myLIST[i]]+([0]*(len(myLIST)-1)) if i>0 else myLIST for i,j in enumerate(myLIST)]
```

```
[[41, 32, 49, 4, 55],
 [32, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [49, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [55, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Since your goal is to master list comprehensions, I would recommend the following guides that I found useful long back with the same -

1. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension
2. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/10-examples-you-should-try-to-master-list-comprehensions-in-python/

---

#### Using a combination of numpy and list comprehension

For completeness, you can do this purely in numpy by using `stride_tricks` or `np.roll` as well.

Check this - [Roll rows of a matrix independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360675/roll-rows-of-a-matrix-independently)

Another approach is to use a combination of `np.roll` and list comprehension with ternary operator conditions on the index -

1. Convert myLIST to a diagonal matrix using `np.diag(myLIST)`

```
array([[41,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 32,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 49,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 55]])
```

2. Next, you can then `np.roll` each of the of the rows in the array independently by the index number * -1. So, for `[ 0,  0, 49,  0,  0]`, -2 roll would result in `[ 49,  0, 0,  0,  0]`
3. Put a condition to roll every thing with index > 0 and when index is 0, just return the original array.

Here is the complete code as a list comprehension -

```
import numpy

arr = np.diag(myLIST)

[list(np.roll(j,-1*i)) if i>0 else myLIST for i,j in enumerate(arr)]
```

```
[[41, 32, 49, 4, 55],
 [32, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [49, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [55, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```