# numpy.roll horizontally on a 2D ndarray with different values

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Doing `np.roll(a, 1, axis = 1)` on:

```
a = np.array([  
             [6, 3, 9, 2, 3],
             [1, 7, 8, 1, 2],
             [5, 4, 2, 2, 4],
             [3, 9, 7, 6, 5],
            ])
```

results in the correct:

```
array([
       [3, 6, 3, 9, 2],
       [2, 1, 7, 8, 1],
       [4, 5, 4, 2, 2],
       [5, 3, 9, 7, 6]
     ])
```

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) says:

> If a tuple, then axis must be a tuple of the same size, and each of the given axes is shifted by the corresponding number.

Now I like to roll rows of `a` by different values, like `[1,2,1,3]` meaning, first row will be rolled by 1, second by 2, third by 1 and forth by 3. But `np.roll(a, [1,2,1,3], axis=(1,1,1,1))` doesn't seem to do it. What would be the correct interpretation of the sentence in the docs?

Comment: This is doing what the docs say it will. Shift axis 1 by 1, then shift axis 1 by 2, etc. which is equivalent to `np.roll(a, 7, axis = 1)`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360675/roll-rows-of-a-matrix-independently) for other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying a tuple in `np.roll` you can roll an array along various axes. For example, `np.roll(a, (3,2), axis=(0,1))` will shift each element of `a` by 3 places along axis 0, and it will also shift each element by 2 places along axis 1. `np.roll` does not have an option to roll each row by a different amount. You can do it though for example as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([  
             [6, 3, 9, 2, 3],
             [1, 7, 8, 1, 2],
             [5, 4, 2, 2, 4],
             [3, 9, 7, 6, 5],
            ])
shifts = np.c_[[1,2,1,3]]
a[np.c_[:a.shape[0]], (np.r_[:a.shape[1]] - shifts) % a.shape[1]]
```

It gives:

```
array([[3, 6, 3, 9, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 7, 8],
       [4, 5, 4, 2, 2],
       [7, 6, 5, 3, 9]])
```