# Left shift each row of 2D Numpy array independently

Tags: python, numpy, vector

```
A = np.array([[4.0, 3, 2],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [0, -1, 5]])

shift = np.array([1,2,1])

out = np.array([[3, 2, np.nan],
              [3, np.nan, np.nan],
              [-1, 5, np.nan]])
```

I want to left shift the 2D numpy array towards the left for each row independently as given by the shift vector and impute the right with Nan.

Please help me out with this

Thanks

Comment: `np.nan` is a float; AFAIK, you can not use it in an integer array

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[4, 3, 2],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [0, -1, 5]])

shift = np.array([1,2,1])


x,y = A.shape
res = np.full(x*y,np.nan).reshape(x,y)

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        res[i][:(y-shift[i])]=A[i][shift[i]:]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Roll rows of matrix [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51613442/)

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows as viewW
import numpy as np


A = np.array([[4, 3, 2],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [0, -1, 5]])

shift = np.array([1,1,1])

p = np.full((A.shape[0],A.shape[1]-1),np.nan)
a_ext = np.concatenate((A,p,p),axis=1)


n = A.shape[1]
shifted =viewW(a_ext,(1,n))[np.arange(len(shift)), -shift + (n-1),0]


print(shifted)
```

output #

```
[[ 3.  2. nan]
 [ 2.  3. nan]
 [-1.  5. nan]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just use a for loop and [np.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) per row.

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[4, 3, 2],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [0, -1, 5]]).astype(float)

shift = np.array([1,2,1])

out = np.copy(A)
for i,shift_value in enumerate(shift):
    out[i,:shift_value] = np.nan
    out[i,:] = np.roll(out[i,:], -shift_value, 0)
print(out)
```

```
[[ 3.  2. nan]
 [ 3. nan nan]
 [-1.  5. nan]]
```

while someone might think that reducing the calls to `np.roll` will help, it won't because this is exactly the way `np.roll` is implemented internally, and you'll have 2 loops in your code instead of 1.

Comment: @vvv not with numpy alone ... you'll have to use something like cython or numba, for almost the same performance.